# Changing theme colour in PowerPoint doesn't affect Treemap

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have tried to change the colour theme of a PP presentation and all elements change including bar charts and pie charts but it has no effect on a Tree Map and the colours have to be manually changed. I am using theme colours and the Tree Map correctly shows the theme colours used but the old ones not the new ones.

Comment: Is this Tree Map a built-in PPT feature or does it come from some other application/add-in?

Comment: @SteveRindsberg Tree Map is a chart type PPT. Other charts bar/pie/line all change when colours change except the Treemap chart type.

Comment: Thanks. I should have looked at the insert chart dialog before asking. Here (Windows/Office 365 subscription, updated w/in the last few days), tree chart colors are changing as I change designs in normal view or when I change the color them in Slide Master view.  Might be worth checking to see if an update's available.